# How to open specific web page after facebook login to my website?

Tags: javascript, java, php, facebook

I integrated facebook login to my website but after doing login it redirects me to https://mywebsite.com instead of https://mywebsite.com/history.php

How can I open https://mywebsite.com/history.php page after login?
I am using PHP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is the login of facebook</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./fbapp/fb.js"></script>

        <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
        {
        include("history.php");
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
     <div class="fb-login-button" id="btn" data-scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Login</div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I added URL but it is still opening https://mywebsite.com below is screenshot 
[image]
Please anyone can help me

Comment: With the login button plugin you are using the client-side login flow; the settings your screenshot refers to are only relevant to the server-side flow. If you want to redirect somewhere else after client-side login, you have to do that yourself - from within the callback function you specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) you can set your redirect page from the dashboard:

> In the App Dashboard, choose your app and go to Products > Facebook Login > Settings. Under the Client OAuth Settings, enter your redirect URL in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs field for successful authorization.

Comment: I did it but it's still same, I added screenshot above

Comment: @SchadrackRurangwa try toggling off that "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" 

Comment: That button is disabled, I cannot toggling it off, is there other settings I can change in order to make it enabled?